# Represent probability with multiple distributions. Archer shooting bullseyes problem.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving

The goal is to come up with two ways to represent this probability:

An archer shoots a bulls-eye with probability $0.4$. If the archer shoots ten arrows, what's the probability that at least 3 are bullseyes?

The first representation I came up with is $X\sim$binomial$(10,0.4)$. To find the probability, I did $1-F(2)$.

What other distributions can be used to represent this question? I suspect the Negative binomial may work, but I can't seem to get the computations to match up.

Comment: You can also add the individual probabilities from 3 to 10

Comment: That's true, but I want a completely separate way to determine the probability. I want to have another random variable $Y$ with a distribution that isn't binomial...

Comment: But you're describing a binomial process. Any way you do it will reduce to a binomial model. You could let $Y=1-X$ then calculate $F_Y(7)$

Comment: Let's say that I want to reduce to a binomial model, but that I want to start first with a distribution that is NOT binomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your question now.

As you guessed, you can use the negative binomial:

Let $Y_i\sim Geometric(0.4)$ is the number of shots to get one bulls eye.

Then $Z=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3\sim NegBinom(3,0.4)$

Then, you want to know $P(Z\leq 10)$

From Excel, the $P(Z\leq 10)$ is the probability of getting 0 to 7 failures and three successes, which give a probability of $83.2\%$ whcih is the same as $1-F_X(2)$ for $X\sim binomial(10,0.4)$

Comment: Can you explain why it's $P(Z\geq 10)$ and not $P(Z\leq 10)$?

Comment: @pocketlizard sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Perfect! This was an example of a separate problem I was trying to solve, and I ended up having to restrict so I was looking at $P(1\leq Z \leq 10)$, but otherwise this was exactly what I was looking for.